# **codeigniter ajax login issue **

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Login issue with ajax and codeigniter, login failed then show error message in script

**ajax script dose not show any action**

```
<script>
     $('#login_form').submit(function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var uname = $('#uname').val();
            var upassword = $('#upassword').val();
            if (uname == "" || upassword == "")
            {
                $('#error').show().html('All Fields are required');
            } else {
                $('#error').html("").hide();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?= base_url(); ?>User_controller/login_autho/",
                    // datatype: 'json',
                    data: {uname: uname, upassword: upassword},
                    success: function (data) {

                        if (data == '1')
                        {
                         window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url(); ?>User_controller/profile");
                        } else {
                            alert('invalid username');
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
</script>
```

**This is a codeigniter controller to check login and open profile.php file**

```
public function login_autho() {
    $data = array(
        'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
        'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
    );
    $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);
    if ($result == TRUE) {
        //adding data to session 
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('user_profile');

    } else if($result==FALSE){
        $this->load->view('user/header');
        $this->load->view('user/login');
   }
}
```

Comment: First of all in your controller condition **if($result == TRUE )** you dint return anything like **return '1'** or **echo '1'**. Unless you return any thing from your controller, ajax cant handle the response **data**

Comment: Your problem lies in the *login_autho()* function. Your ajax call expects the result as **1**, but you are actually returning a big chunk of html within header and profile views.

Comment: that works perfect thanks but i have one more question  that is if username and password is invalid then how to handle it

Answer (score 0):

This would solve your need

```
if ($result == TRUE) 
{
    return '1';
} 
else if($result==FALSE)
{
  return '0';
}
```

In your ajax succes function do these

```
success: function (data) 
{
   if (data == '1')
   {
      window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url(); ?>User_controller/profile");
   }
   else 
   {
       window.location.href("<?php echo base_url(); ?>User_controller/login");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return value `1` or `0` from controller

```
public function login_autho() 
{
    $data = array(
    'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
    'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
    );
    $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);
    if ($result == TRUE) {
        echo 1;

    } else if($result==FALSE){
        echo 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it's works for me

```
 public function login_autho() 
    {
        $data = array(
        'uname' => $this->input->post('uname'),
        'upassword' => $this->input->post('upassword')
        );
        $result = $this->login_model->login_user($data);
        if ($result == TRUE) {
            echo 1;

    } else if($result==FALSE){
        echo 0;
    }
}
```